# Git merge: get conflicts as separate files for merge with external tool

Tags: git

When i pull, I got a conflict, but as usual the conflict is marked inline in the conflicted file.

I'd like to get "mine" and "theirs" as two/three separate files (.MINE, .THEIRS) so that I can use a special tool for this file type to perform the merge.

Is this possible with git?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes.  When a merge stops with conflicts, the index contains *all three* input files (not just `ours` and `theirs`, but also the *base* version from the merge-base commit).

The work-tree file that you've been looking at is not something Git really cares about very much.  Git will write to the work-tree its best effort at merging the three inputs from the index—the thing Git *does* care about here—and your job, as the human overseeing the merge, is to then come up with the *correct* merge result and stuff it back into the index.  If you can do that with just the mess Git left behind in the work-tree, great.  If not ...:

The index normally has just one copy of each file.  That one copy goes in "slot zero", and initially, it matches the commit you checked-out.

The work-tree copy of the file is there for *you* to use, but Git doesn't really use it, except when you run `git add file`.  Then Git copies the work-tree copy of the file over top of the index copy, so that the index copy matches the work-tree copy again (and likely no longer matches the current-commit copy).

During a merge, the slot-zero copy winds up in slot 2 (`--ours`).  The copy of that same file from the merge base goes into slot 1.  The copy of that same file from the other commit—the one you're merging—goes into slot 3 (`--theirs`).  Git attempts to combine all three copies, and if Git succeeds on its own, Git puts the combined version in slot zero (and copies it out to the work-tree) and empties out the merge slots.  If Git fails, it leaves the merge slots occupied, with slot zero empty.

So if the work-tree mess that Git left behind is not good enough, you can just extract all three index copies.  The way to do that manually is using `git checkout-index`, but a generally-easier (if rather klunky) way to do it is to use `git mergetool`.

[The `git mergetool` command](https://mirrors.edge.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-mergetool.html) is essentially a large shell script that runs `git checkout-index` on all three copies of each as-yet-unmerged file, then runs any command of your choice on those three copies.  That command should write the correct merged file to a fourth file:

> ... the
>    configured command line will be invoked with `$BASE` set to the name
>    of a temporary file containing the common base for the merge, if
>    available; `$LOCAL` set to the name of a temporary file containing
>    the contents of the file on the current branch; `$REMOTE` set to the
>    name of a temporary file containing the contents of the file to be
>    merged, and `$MERGED` set to the name of the file to which the merge
>    tool should write the result of the merge resolution.

Again, all these temporary files are made by `git mergetool` using `git checkout-index` to extract them from the index.  When your tool finishes, the script uses `git add` on the `$MERGED` file to remove the slot 1-3 entries and write a slot-zero entry.

The phrase *if available* appears above because in a few corner cases, the merge conflict has occurred because one file is *missing*.  For instance, an *add/add conflict* occurs when there's no *merge base* version of `newfile.ext`, but both `--ours` and `--theirs` *do* have a `newfile.ext` and the two files don't match.  Here, the base will be missing; `$LOCAL` and `$REMOTE` will both exist.  A *modify/delete conflict* occurs when `file.ext` existed in the base commit, you (`--ours`) or they (`--theirs`) *changed* the file, and the other one of you / they *removed* the file.  Here, `$BASE` will exist, but only one of `$LOCAL` or `$REMOTE` will exist.

Since `git mergetool` *is* a [shell script](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/git-mergetool.sh), you can copy and modify it—you'll need a few adjacent files; explore from here and they should be obvious—if you want to change its operation in some way that isn't already supported via flags and tool configuration.

Answer (score 1):

Set up a `mergetool`, that Git will open when you run `git mergetool`. Git provides 4 variables with paths, which you can feed to the command that will open your tool. From `man git-mergetool`:

> When `git mergetool` is invoked with this tool (either through the `-t` or `--tool` option or the `merge.tool` configuration variable) the configured command line will be invoked with `$BASE` set to the name of a temporary file containing the common base for the merge, if available; `$LOCAL` set to the name of a temporary file containing the contents of the file on the current branch; `$REMOTE` set to the name of a temporary file containing the contents of the file to be merged, and `$MERGED` set to the name of the file to which the merge tool should write the result of the merge resolution.

That could for example look like:

```
[merge]
    tool = vimdiff

[mergetool "vimdiff"]
    cmd = vimdiff $LOCAL $BASE $REMOTE $MERGED -c '$wincmd w | wincmd J'
```